# How to use jQuery to load codepress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using codepress in a CMS to edit files in the filesystem. Everything works nicely, however when trying to load the same page using jQuery load() function, codepress seems to break.

My javascript code looks like this which loads the php file with codpress, however codepress seems to not fire.

```
$('.content').on('click', '#fileSystemWrap a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).data('file');
    $('#rightColWrap').fadeOut(150, function(){
        $('#rightColWrap').load('/?url=developer/edit-file.php&open=' + fileName, function(){
            $('#rightColWrap').fadeIn(150);
        });
    });
});
```

Digging into codepress.js I see this at the end of the file but I'm not understanding if there is something I could add to my initial on click event listner script to help codpress fire.

```
if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload',CodePress.run);
else window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',CodePress.run,false);
```

Here is the link to codepress on sourceforge
https://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/

Comment: try this after load method is complete and add after $('#rightColWrap').fadeIn(150) this code

CodePress.initialize('new');

Comment: That did not work, it killed the click event.

Comment: what you got editor result this code. But you did pass inside click event.

Comment: user5200704 I am not sure what you mean? Could you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that we needed to add parentheses to CodePress.run and after the fadeIn() call.

```
$('#content').on('click', '#fileSystemWrap a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).data('file');
    $('#content').fadeOut(150, function(){
        $('#content').load('/?url=developer/edit-file.php&open=' + fileName, function(){
            $('#content').fadeIn(150, function(){
                CodePress.run();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

To be logic : when the data are loaded, we want to initialize CodePress.
So your code should look like :

```
$('.content').on('click', '#fileSystemWrap a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).data('file');
    $('#rightColWrap').fadeOut(150, function(){
        $('#rightColWrap').load('/?url=developer/edit-file.php&open=' + fileName, function(){
            CodePress.run();
            $('#rightColWrap').fadeIn(150);
        });
    });
});
```

If this didn't work please provide error from the console.

Edit : corrected answer, seen Robson França's comment.
Last issue was that `CodePress.run;` should have been written `CodePress.run();`

Comment: This did not work. There was no error in the console except An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. However, I was able to re-write some of the codepress.js code to remove this error, however it still will not file after the load() function. I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: I am still perplexed by this issue. I know that the codpress.js does not use $(document).ready(function(){ I still think it has something to do with this line of code in codepress.js if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload',CodePress.run);
else window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',CodePress.run,false);

Comment: The solution above seems correct. However I'd add parens at CodePress.run line: CodePress.run()

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Just add CodePress.run() instead of CodePress.run